# How to insert a formula by macro?

Tags: excel, vba

The issue has been solved.

It would appear that when I made some changes to capture data a little while ago, I inadvertently broke the order of things. When the above bit of code was running, the `[Date Out:]` column was indeed empty, so Excel was reporting properly.

I've since reordered the input of formulas and now the sheet works correctly, with credit to @BigBen and @Michael Wycisk.

---

I created an Excel sheet to draw together the data from several other Excel sheets into one to keep track of a project.

I have a formula that works if it is written into a range of cells with the source data sheet open in the background. If I ask a macro to put it into the required cells as the main sheet opens then the formula fails. By 'fail', I mean the formula checks it's first column to see if data is present or not and then decides that the column is empty regardless, therefore falsely reporting 'nothing sent' if there is a date in the "Date Out" column.

Here is the line in question.

```
WSR.Range("ReportTable[Latest Portare Instance:]") = "=IFERROR(IF([Date out:]="""",""Nothing Sent"",IF(AND([Received by Serial:]="""",[Received by Asset:]=""""),""Not Received"",IF([Received by Asset:]<>"""",LOOKUP(2,1/('Stock Movement Archive Defra.xlsx'!Archive[Asset No:]=$J2),'Stock Movement Archive Defra.xlsx'!Archive[Location:]),LOOKUP(2,1/('Stock Movement Archive Defra.xlsx'!Archive[S/No:]=$I2),'Stock Movement Archive Defra.xlsx'!Archive[Location:])))),""Issue"")"
```

It's one of several formulas, all inserted the same way and the rest work. As far as I can tell the formula is being inserted correctly, just that this one stops at the first if statement.

For reference, I have tried changing the first 'if' statement to start `IF([Date out:]<>""""`, the formula then either states "Nothing Received" where there is no date or pulls the correct data if there is a date. Also tried changing the format of the "Date Out" column.

Comment: Does evaluating the formula with *Formulas* > *Evaluate Formula* give  you any more detail?

Comment: Thank you @BigBen, but running the evaluation didn't throw up any issues.

Comment: How does Excel know where `'Stock Movement Archive Defra.xlsx'` is saved? You need the full path if the workbook isn't open.

Comment: The macro opens the required source sheet so that the data can be retrieved, once done it then closes the source sheet.

Comment: Can you then explain what "but if I ask a macro to put it into the required cells as the main sheet opens then the formula fails"? What does "as the main sheet opens" mean? Maybe we need more code.

Comment: So the macro opens the file and closes it, right? What happens if you add a `Application.Calculate` after you insert the formula? @LJW

Answer (score 0):

The formula looks fine for me. The only problem might be that you need to use the `.Formula` property after the Range object:

```
WSR.Range("ReportTable[Latest Portare Instance:]").Formula = "=IFERROR(IF([Date out:]="""",""Nothing Sent"",IF(AND([Received by Serial:]="""",[Received by Asset:]=""""),""Not Received"",IF([Received by Asset:]<>"""",LOOKUP(2,1/('Stock Movement Archive Defra.xlsx'!Archive[Asset No:]=$J2),'Stock Movement Archive Defra.xlsx'!Archive[Location:]),LOOKUP(2,1/('Stock Movement Archive Defra.xlsx'!Archive[S/No:]=$I2),'Stock Movement Archive Defra.xlsx'!Archive[Location:])))),""Issue"")"
```

To make sure that your formula is correct (you say it works fine when typed into the cell), you might type it into the cell, select the cell and then type `?ActiveCell.Formula` into the Immediate Window inside the VBE (don't forget to check that the quotation marks are correct).

Comment: Hi @Michael Wycisk, adding the `.formula` property to the code didn't have any effect, i'm afraid. The formula still stops at the first "If" statement.

Comment: I just see that you reference an external sheet `Stock Movement Archive Defra.xlsx`. Is that open when you test the formula? You can check if a full reference with file path makes a difference. Besides that, any chance to have a look at the file?

Comment: Yes, the source sheet is open while testing the formula. And the macro also opens up the required source sheet while it's running to mine the data, then closes it afterwards. Unfortunately, I can't share the actual file due to company policy, just snippets of code.

Comment: Really strange. One more thing I remember is that updating connections to SharePoint/OneDrive can be tricky. But that is probably not the case here?